# Does anybody know how to change the font for "Run" Console window?

Tags: android, android-studio

It doesn't go with the global font setting in Android Studio.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes you can change

Go to the `File -> settings` in that `Editor-> Colors & Fonts` in that go to the console font and in that you need to create new scheme name and change it.

you cannot modify the default one.

what are fonts are available you need to choose that and in the selected fonts you need to give the top priority by moving it by arrows at right side.

[image]

Comment: How do I change the `Terminal` font?

Comment: Actual solution is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065637/android-studio-how-to-increase-the-size-of-logcat-text