# Android Studio: How to increase the size of logcat text?

Tags: android-studio

Anybody knows where can I increase the size of logcat text? There's no setting for it in the main settings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30067023/776345

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Go to file-> Settings-> Editor-> Colors & Font -> Console Font

Though to change the saved settings, you will have to create a new scheme or save the existing scheme with a new name(see the top of the screenshot.[image])

Comment: Don't miss that you have to change the **Console Font** page, even though the screen shot shows the **Android Logcat** page.

Comment: This makes the console font HUGE, though. So either logcat is to tiny to read or the terminal uses too big font size to be usable?

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to @params  for his answer  but here is the correct screen shot

`File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `Colors & Font` > `Console Font`

In size column give your size ,ex :- 18 click Ok

[image]

**UPDATE**

from android studio 3.1.2 it is in `Settings` > `Editor` > `Color Scheme` > `Console Font`

[image]

Comment: The update for version 3.1.2 appears to be valid for Android Studio 2021.3.1.17 but for some strange reason it does not affect LogCat's font size. Even after IDE restart.

Answer (score 6):

Now in AS 3.1.2 the font settings are under "Editor -> Color Scheme -> Console Font" which is misleading.