# How to change logcat font size in Android Studio 1.0.0?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

How to change logcat font size in Android Studio 1.0.0?

I only found way to change the font color in Android Studio.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Logcat is just using the font settings of Console Font.
To change this in Android Studio, go to:

> Settings->Editor->Color & Fonts->Console Font

Comment: It changes the overall font size. But I found I can use CTRL+mouse wheel to ajdust only the logcat font.

Comment: @Seraphim's Ctrl+mouse wheel does not adjust the logcat font in Android Studio version 2021.3

Comment: @Seraphim's Ctrl+mouse wheel only changes LogCat's font in Android Studio version 2021.3 if the File > Settings > Editor > General relevant checkbox is checked as depicted in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-increase-editor-font-size-in-android-studio/